# SQL Server: Unable to consolidate multiple rows into one row based on same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server trying to consolidate multiple rows with the same account name into one row based on account, but I can't use GROUP BY since it wants me to group all of the columns as well (which just nets me the same result).

Here's what my table currently looks like.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| service_id | account    | Aug Aide Billed | Aug Trans Billed | Sept Aide Billed | Sept Trans Billed | 
|    001A    | John Smith |        1        |         0        |          0       |         0         | 
|    001A    | John Smith |        0        |         1        |          0       |         0         |
|    001A    | John Smith |        0        |         0        |          1       |         0         |
|    001A    | John Smith |        0        |         0        |          0       |         1         |
|    001B    | John Smith |        1        |         0        |          0       |         0         | 
|    001B    | John Smith |        0        |         1        |          0       |         0         |
|    001B    | John Smith |        0        |         0        |          1       |         0         |
|    001B    | John Smith |        0        |         0        |          0       |         1         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And here's what I want it  to look like.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| service_id | account    | Aug Aide Billed | Aug Trans Billed | Sept Aide Billed | Sept Trans Billed | 
|    001A    | John Smith |        1        |         1        |          1       |         1         | 
|    001B    | John Smith |        1        |         1        |          1       |         1         | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here's my query that I'm using:

```
select service_id, account,
case when (date_from between '2021-08-01' and '2021-08-31') and posted_flag = 'y' and service_id = '001A' then 1 else 0 end as 'Aug Aide Billed',
case when (date_from between '2021-08-01' and '2021-08-31') and posted_flag = 'y' and service_id in ('001B', '001C') then 1 else 0 end as 'Aug Trans Billed',
case when (date_from between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-30') and posted_flag = 'y' and service_id = '001A' then 1 else 0 end as 'Sept Aide Billed',
case when (date_from between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-30') and posted_flag = 'y' and service_id in ('001B', '001C') then 1 else 0 end as 'Sept Trans Billed',
from table1 r
join table2 p
on r.id = p.id
where p.account = 'John Smith'
and r.service_id like '001%'
and date_from between DATEFROMPARTS('2021',8,1) and DATEFROMPARTS('2021',9,31)
```

I've tried using GROUP BY account or service_id, but this doesn't work because SQL wants me to group by every other column which just nets me the same results.

Comment: it is better if you can provide a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: What you provided as sample data does not line up with the query you provided. There are several columns in your query not in your sample data. Not sure why you are using DATEFROMPARTS here. I would just use a date string in YYYYMMDD format (i.e. '20210801'). Also, the between operator is not usually a good idea, especially with dates. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: not enough input what are those dates in the query, you can use as reference this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eec69/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using many fields to filter out information, you can use a subquery to apply your aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT service_id, 
           account,
           CASE WHEN (date_from between '2021-08-01' and '2021-08-31') and posted_flag = 'y' and service_id = '001A' 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'Aug Aide Billed',
           CASE WHEN (date_from between '2021-08-01' and '2021-08-31') and posted_flag = 'y' and service_id in ('001B', '001C') 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Aug Trans Billed',
           CASE WHEN (date_from between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-30') and posted_flag = 'y' and service_id = '001A' 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Sept Aide Billed',
           CASE WHEN (date_from between '2021-09-01' and '2021-09-30') and posted_flag = 'y' and service_id in ('001B', '001C') 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Sept Trans Billed',
    FROM table1 r
    JOIN table2 p ON r.id = p.id
    WHERE p.account = 'John Smith'
      AND r.service_id like '001%'
      AND date_from BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS('2021',8,1) AND DATEFROMPARTS('2021',9,31)
)
SELECT service_id, account,
       SUM('Aug Aide Billed'  ) AS 'Aug Aide Billed',
       SUM('Aug Trans Billed' ) AS 'Aug Trans Billed',
       SUM('Sept Aide Billed' ) AS 'Sept Aide Billed',
       SUM('Sept Trans Billed') AS 'Sept Trans Billed'
FROM cte
GROUP BY service_id, account
```